# Strange Chrome TD background-color issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

A combination of CSS causes a strange issue in Chrome and not Safari or Firefox.

I'm using a `max-height` transition to hide the content when the input isn't focused:

```
.suggestions {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus ~ .suggestions {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

I also have CSS to set the `background-color` of a table cell when it's got the selected class.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: light-blue;
}
td.selected {
  background-color: dark-blue;
}
```

On Firefox and Safari everything works fine, but on Chrome when I focus the `input`, the `background-color` is missing.

Is this a Chrome bug or am I missing something?

How it should look:

[image]

How it Actually Looks:

[image]

You can see this issue in this jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/a7mboskj/.
Focus on the input in chrome and the 2nd cell won't have a green background. In Safari or Firefox it does have the green background.

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: Example jsfiddle added. Thanks @alirezasafian

Comment: I just vote to reopen the question.

Comment: I think this is a chrome bug. For example, if you remove transition, it will be worked or try to resize the window.

Comment: I checked your code with different techniques, I think chrome have a bug by `table` you can change your `html` and use *other elements* or you can reduce `animation-duration`(for example` 0.3s`).

Comment: i don't what exactly happen with chrome but try to force repaint the td using javascript  and i make a little change in your css so it is work now 
https://jsfiddle.net/a7mboskj/3/

,,, i think the problem is with the `display:table-cell'

Comment: Chrome has been buggy with the background of the tables for so many versions that I can't remember which one was the first. Don't expect it to be fixed anytime soon. (Hopefully I am wrong)

Comment: Very strange. I have a machine which is running Chrome v38 and the green background does show up. So, it looks like regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had noted in comments, `td.selected` does show up with green background in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.101 m but it does not work in the latest Chrome. It seems to be a regression in behavior or possibly an informed decision to make it not work. I can't comment on why the behavior has changed but in my opinion it is a regression.

There is a however a fix available for the latest version of Chrome. The part that seems to be causing the trouble is the `background-color: white` that is applied to the `tr`. Remove it from `tr` and apply the white background to the `td` instead. This seems to make it work properly.

This works fine in Chrome v48.0.2564.22 dev-m, Chrome v38.0.2125.101 m, Safari v5.1.7 (on Win 7) IE11, IE10, IE9, Edge, Opera and Firefox.

```css
.suggestions {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus ~ .suggestions {
  max-height: 500px;
}
table, input {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  /* background-color: white; remove this */
}
td {
  width: 14.258%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white; /* add it here */
}
td:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
td.selected, td.selected:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="suggestions">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="selected">2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, I've also posted a bug report to Google, so we'll see what happens.

Comment: You're welcome @maddi.joyce. Glad that I could be of help :)